# Windows 10 check what woke up my computer

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep

I have a Lenovo Thinkbook 13s plugged in to power supply and my main monitor (Acer ET430K, which I use for entertainment instead of a TV) while it's at home. The laptop itself is closed, and I use an external keyboard-touchpad (Logitech K400+).

For some reason, the computer doesn't sleep properly. It would sleep, and after some time it would wake back up. I haven't witnessed the precise time of waking up yet, but at some point it would just wake itself up, either while I'm at work or when I'm sleeping. I have no idea why. I'm very sure it's not the external keyboard itself because I turn it off when I put the computer to sleep.

Is there a way to check, in Windows 10, the cause of my computer waking up? Like, what woke it up?

Comment: Event viewer should indicate when and what woke it up.

Comment: Make sure you use Suspend and not Hibernate or Hybrid Sleep. You can use POWERCFG  /LASTWAKE from an admin command prompt to see when it is waking up

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thank you. Would you expand on that in an answer? When I open Event Viewer, I don't really know what I'm looking at.